# Como cortar uma frase e colocar os resultados em strings

Tags: php

como faço para dividir uma string (em PHP) a partir de strings que já tenho, por exemplo:

```
$frase = 'tem refrigerante na geladeira';
$pergunta = 'tem';
$local = 'na geladeira';
```

aí queria que ele trouxesse no $item a palavra refrigerante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um replace:

```
$frase = 'tem refrigerante na geladeira';
$pergunta = 'tem';
$local = 'na geladeira';

$output  = str_replace($pergunta , "" , $frase);
$output  = str_replace($local , "", $output);

var_dump($output);

//Ou fazer um array e tirar tudo dele
$frase = 'tem refrigerante na geladeira';
$ar = array("na geladeira", "tem");
$output= str_replace($ar , "", $frase);

var_dump($output);
```

O str_replace basicamente substitui na string o que ele achar igual ao procurado:

```
str_replace("o devo procurar?" , "se achar, substituo por isso", "eu procuro aqui");
```

Comment: deu certo, valeu!!

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo de nada

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um `preg_replace` (*replace usando regex*). Irá pegar tudo que estiver em `$pergunta` e `$local` e fazer um replace na `$frase`, restando o que sobrar (no caso, `refrigerante`):

```
$frase = 'tem refrigerante na geladeira';
$pergunta = 'tem';
$local = 'na geladeira';

$item = trim(preg_replace("/$pergunta|$local/", "", $frase));

echo $item; // retorna -> refrigerante
```

[**Veja no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/eMjBib)